# Javascript fillRect on canvas with absolute position inside a relative container

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have two canvases inside a container like this:

```
<div class="canvasContainer">
   <canvas class="drawCanvas" style="z-index: 0;"></canvas>
   <canvas class="drawCanvas" height="150" width="300" style="z-index: 1;"></canvas>
</div>
```

The first canvas (z-index 0) contains an image and the second canvas is for drawing. Both canvas have a position absolute and the canvasContainer has a relative position, but for some reason the fillRect function on the canvas context does not work when I apply the relative postion to the canvasContainer. When I remove the relative postion the fillRect function in Javascript does work, but then my canvas is positioned absolute to the body tag. Why does the fillRect function not work inside my canvasContainer when its postion is relative?

This is how I draw on my canvas

```
let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.style.zIndex = "0";
        canvas.className = "drawCanvas";
        let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        img.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        }

        canvasContainer.appendChild(canvas);

        let canvas2 = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas2.className = "drawCanvas";
        canvas2.style.zIndex = "1";
        canvas2.height = canvas.height;
        canvas2.width = canvas.width;
        canvas2.md = false;
        canvas2.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event){
            this.md = true;
        });

        canvas2.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event){
            this.md = false;
        });

        canvas2.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event){
            let mouseX = event.clientX - this.offsetLeft;
            let mouseY = event.clientY - this.offsetTop;

            if(this.md){
                let ctx = this.getContext('2d');
                    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
                    ctx.fillRect(mouseX, mouseY, 4, 4);
                }
            }
        });

        imageContainer.appendChild(canvas2);



    }
```

Comment: I would think that the z-indexing is your problem and that the mouse event listeners on your canvas are not being fired because of it. Make sure you set both css position and z-index on the container and both canvases. Usually for z-index problems, you need to have position set on the parent and children.

Comment: Also... you mention you have 2 canvases (both in the html), but then you create a new canvas with JS and add it to "imageContainer", now you have 3 canvases... where is "imageContainer"?

Comment: I've tried adding z-index to all containers, but the draw function only works if I remove the position relative on my canvasContainer